# dynamic content header and footer information overwrite in print view

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, printing

```js
function PrintPage() {
          document.getElementById('print').style.display = 'none';
          window.resizeTo(960, 600);
          document.URL = "";
          window.location.href = "";
          window.print();
      }
```

```css
@page { size: auto;  margin: 2mm 4mm 0mm 0mm; }
.theadclass{top:0;position:fixed;display:block;height:100px;width:100%;border:solid 2px red;background-color:red;overflow:hidden;z-index:1;clear:both}.tfootclass{bottom:0;position:fixed;display:block;height:100px;clear:both;width:100%;border:solid 2px red;overflow:hidden;background-color:#000}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <br clear="all"/>
   <input type="button" id="print" name="print" value="Print" onclick="javascript:PrintPage();" class="button" />
     <div class="theadclass"> header content here</div>
   <div class="tbodyclass">
     <?php 
        for ($i=0; $i < 150; $i++) { 
              echo "".$i."<br/>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
  <div class="tfootclass"> footer content here </div>
</form>
```

Comment: what you want ?

Comment: set static header and footer same image in all pages

Comment: try include();  php function to load header and footer

Comment: i want to set in print view - CTRL+P